# vimrc - how to block comment?

Tags: vimrc, block-comment

I don't want to comment lines of text in a text file or code. I am looking for inserting block comments in a *.vimrc* file. To insert a single line comment `"` is used, for example:

```
" remove spaces and tabs as well  at the end of line automatically while saving
autocmd BufWritePre * :%s/\s\+$//e
```

Now I've got a relatively large amount of settings/configs/plugins collected over the years after browsing through the internet to add cool features. I'm looking to add some large comment blocks to my .vimrc file. Adding `"` to each line is a option but I am looking for a block comment syntax. Similar to `/**/` in C.

`//` is identical to `"`
`/* */` is identical to ***_*____** ?

Searching Unix.SE, SO and googling didn't help much.

Comment: I suspect multi-line comments feature does not exist in vim-config files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not think this is possible. The best you'll be able to do is block select some text, and do a search/replace on the first character `s/^/"/` in vim to insert a `"` to the beginning of each line.

The vim plugin [NERD Commenter](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1218) might help make this easier as well.

Comment: I use the workaround :.,+3s/^/"/ where dot represents current line and +3 represents amount of consecutive (after the dot line) lines.

Answer (score 10):

My solution is to wrap the code inside a `function`.

This works well in vimrc, e.g., for in-place [heredoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) syntax highlighting tests, which also require real block comments without leading characters. In my vimrc, I use such a block directly after setting up my heredoc [SyntaxRanges](https://github.com/vim-scripts/SyntaxRange).

```
function! _blockcomment()

    " free text comment
    You can write free text here,
    but vim will try to highlight it as vimscript!

    " markdown heredoc
    test <<MD
    ### Nevertheless ###
    * for testing my fuzzy SyntaxRange heredocs
    * having no leading chars is essential
    * and the blockcomment function does the trick
    MD  

endfunction
```

This solution is similar to @Stéphane's `if 0` trick, which did not work for me. Just make sure to never call this function!

Answer (score 3):

There is this life changing plugin by `tpope` called `vim-commentary`

https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary

**This plugin provides**:

- Sanity
- Properly indented comments
- Does not comment out empty/unnecessary lines

**Usage**:

- Install via Vundle (or Pathogen I guess).
- Highlight your text and press `:` which will show as `:<,'>`
- Type Commentary here `:<,'>Commentary` and press enter.
- Bom. Your done bud.

Answer (score 2):

One trick:

- place your cursor on the first character of the first line to comment
- press Ctrl-V to enter in Visual Block mode
- get your cursor down until the last line to comment
- press I (shift+i) to enter in conditional insert mode
- press '" ' to comment (a quote and a space)
- press Esc to quit insert mode

All your selected lines are now prepended by the string you typed in insert mode.

Comment: Thanks but I was looking for what exactly is the block comment style in _vimrc_.

Comment: I don't think there is such a feature in vim. By the way, it's not so common. In a lot of script languages, it's more usual to use single-line comments on a range of lines.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `tComment` plugin for Vim: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1173

Yes, it does support Python (added in 2011).

> description :TComment works like a toggle, i.e., it will comment out
>   text that  contains uncommented lines, and it will uncomment already 
>   commented text (i.e. text that contains no uncommented lines).
>
> If the file-type is properly defined, :TComment will figure out which 
>   comment string to use based on the values of &commentstring or
>   &comments.  For some filetypes, the comment definition is explicitly
>   defined. You can  |tcomment#DefineType()| to add your own definitions.
>
> TComment knows how to deal with embedded code of a different filetype 
>   than the main filetype, e.g., ruby/python/perl regions in vim scripts,
>   HTML or  JavaScript in php code etc.
>
> As operator (the prefix can be customized via g:tcommentMapLeaderOp1 
>   and g:tcommentMapLeaderOp2):
>
> ```
> gc{motion}   :: Toggle comments (for small comments within one line 
>                 the &filetype_inline style will be used, if 
>                 defined) 
> gcc          :: Toggle comment for the current line 
> gC{motion}   :: Comment region 
> gCc          :: Comment the current line
> ```
>
> Primary key maps:
>
> ```
> <c-_><c-_>   :: :TComment 
> <c-_><space> :: :TComment <QUERY COMMENT-BEGIN ?COMMENT-END> 
> <c-_>b       :: :TCommentBlock 
> <c-_>a       :: :TCommentAs <QUERY COMMENT TYPE> 
> <c-_>n       :: :TCommentAs &filetype <QUERY COUNT> 
> <c-_>s       :: :TCommentAs &filetype_<QUERY COMMENT SUBTYPE> 
> <c-_>i       :: :TCommentInline 
> <c-_>r       :: :TCommentRight 
> <c-_>p       :: Comment the current inner paragraph
> ```
>
> There is also a secondary set of key maps with _ as leader
>   (more  preferable on terminals).